# Better way of splitting and assigning many values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, loops, split

I have a for loop that cycles through the number of elements that the user has created. There are a lot of available settings in this plugin, and each element can receive it's specific settings.

1. User settings are entered in the following format: **speed_x: "1000,500 > 1000,200 > 0,0"**
   This controls the speed_x in/out for *3 separate elements*. The **>** divides by object and the commas separate the in/out.
2. So I can grab specific object speed_x values, I've split speed_x into speed_x_set (splitting by >) resulting in:

> 1    1000,500
>         2    1000,200
>         3    0,0`

3 Inside the loop, I grab the value by index (since it's the object #) and split it by comma (to get speed_x_in and speed_x_out.)

```
for(var i=0; i<OS.numberofobjects; ++i){
   OS.speed_x_on_set[i]=speed_x_set[i].split(",")[0],
   OS.speed_x_off_set[i]=speed_x_set[i].split(",")[1],
   ...
};
```

Everything is assigned by object and by setting in/out correctly into the master OS settings object. T***he problem is I have many, many settings which need to be split in this fashion...*** for example: delay_x_set, speed_y_set, opacity_set, etc. Their names are all based on the default setting name, with "_set" added as shown above. Hopefully this provides enough information. Thanks!

Comment: I would assign `speed_x_set[objindex].split(",")` to variable first, to avoid splitting the value twice.

Comment: Using `i` for your loop variable would also help with the visual noise.

Comment: Upvote for using i as iterator variable in the loop. It really helps to read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to cache the split result

```
for(var objindex=0; objindex<OS.numberofobjects; ++objindex){
   var splits = speed_x_set[objindex].split(","); //Cache the split so its does not need to be done twice
   OS.speed_x_on_set[objindex] = splits[0];
   OS.speed_x_off_set[objindex] = splits[1];
   ...
};
```

Comment: Why would I want to cache the results? I'm not sure I follow, but the loop will 1) hit object1, 2) Go into the speed_x_set which contains all of the speed values entered 3) Find the correct speed value (which looks like "1000,1000" for "in,out") 4) Split the value and assign the 1st value to the OS.speed_x_on_set and 2nd to OS.speed_x_off_set..... How would caching the result work into this correctly? Thanks!

Comment: @Aaron: In your code you are doing `speed_x_set[objindex].split(",")` twice. I.e. it has to lookup `speed_x_set[objindex]` and split the string two times, instead of just once in @Starx' code. That's the only improvement you can do though (without having any more information about the overall problem).

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid to access to the same item twice and perform the same `split` twice for each iteration. So, you could have something like:

```
for (var i = 0, item; item = speed_x_set[i++];) {
  var values = item.split(",");
  OS.speed_x_on_set.push(values[0]);
  OS.speed_x_off_set.push(values[1]);
}
```

Notice that in JavaScript 1.7 (Firefox) you can simply have:

```
for (var i = 0, item; item = speed_x_set[i++];) {
  var [on, off] = item.split(",");
  OS.speed_x_on_set.push(on);
  OS.speed_x_off_set.push(off);
}
```

And hopefully in the next version of ECMAScript as well.
It's called "destructuring assignment".

Comment: Awww, that's awesome and makes sense, thanks! The problem though is I have about 60 settings so the actual loop code is quite long. They're all doing the same thing though. For example: The user can set speed_x on 3 objects like so: speed_x:"1000,500 > 1000,500 > 200,500". The first 2 objects have speed_x_in of 1000 and speed_x_out of 500. The 3rd object has speed_x_in of 200 and out of 500. They're first split by object ( > ) into the speed_x_set (so I have speed_x_set = index 1: 1000,500, index 2: 1000,500 ... etc. From there I need to split by comma and push into the OS.speed_x_set.

Comment: The code I posted works well, just seems like a ton of code. So, I also have for example delay_x (which is written the exact same way). I'm not sure how to accomplish this... thanks!

Comment: Not sure I follow you, I should probably see the actual code. However, you can already reduce a bit of code doing only one split:  `values = speed_x.split(/,| > /);` then you have an array with all values and you know they are in pairs, and you can iterate them. About different object, you can also iterate them: Let say, you have `MyValues = {}; MyValues.speed_x = "..."; MyValues.speed_y = "...";` you can just have: `for (var prop in MyValues) doSomething(MyValues[prop])`; Something like that.

Comment: I've tried doing that, and figured it would be a for in loop, but it's always throwing a syntax error in Dreamweaver as soon as I put a for in loop inside a for each loop... I've even tried copying a for in that I have elsewhere (throwing no errors) inside the for each and it still flags it.

Comment: well, except Firefox browsers doesn't have `for each` loop. Only `for…in` and `for` loop. I also do not use DW and it's possible that is the editor itself to have some issue – or, the actual code you're writing is not correct. You could provide to use a bit more code of the *actual* problem maybe, using http://jsfiddle.net or http://pastebin.com or similar.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called [parallel assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29#Parallel_assignment), but unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't have it.

In ruby, however, it is common to see similar patterns:

```
first, second = "first second".split
```

As others have noted, the obvious way would be to cache split results and assign them separately. Sorry for not answering your question directly.